# Tenancy for laravel - Remove key from data column

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm using the [Tenancy For Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) package. What do i need to do to remove a key from the auto generated data column after tenant creation.

I'm using it to store info about the user that created it and the domain and creating those models in a queued job.
After job is done i would like to clean it up a bit and remove those parameters from the data column.

Answer (score 1):

**[⚠️]** I haven't really found a way to remove keys from the data column and it seems like an impossible task - tried disabling events and updating the data column manually, etc. Everything I could find. However it's not required to achieve what OP wants to do.

You can use JobPipelines provided by tenancy to create your own pipeline and pass your data (like a user email) through it.

## How it will work:

You call your own event, let's say TenantSetup, which will initiate a JobPipeline and pass it the email. We'll have a CreateUser job on this pipeline and create a user with the email.

## The setup:

### `TenantSetup` event:

How to create events: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#defining-events

```php
/**
 * Initiates tenant setup.
 */
class TenantSetup extends TenantEvent
{
    use Dispatchable;

    // additional properties we want to pass through the pipeline
    public string $userEmail;

    public function __construct(Tenant $tenant, string $userEmail)
    {
        parent::__construct($tenant);
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;
    }
}
```

### `CreateUser` job:

How to create jobs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#creating-jobs

```php
class CreateUser implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable,
        InteractsWithQueue,
        Queueable,
        SerializesModels;

    protected Tenant $tenant;

    protected string $userEmail;

    // job pipeline passes us data through the constructor
    public function __construct(Tenant $tenant, string $userEmail) {
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;
        $this->tenant = $tenant;
    }

    public function handle() {
        // create a user entry on the tenant with email given
        $tenant->run(function () {
            User::query()
              ->create([
                  'email' => $this->userEmail
              ]);
        })
    }
}
```

### `TenancyProvider#events()` modifications:

More here: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/event-system

We include some of the default Jobs ran after a tenant is created. If you already have these in `Events\TenantCreated` pipeline, remove them.

⚠️Note that the pipeline will not be triggered each time you create a new tenant through models or queries. You will have to call `TenantSetup` each time you create a new tenant.

```php
TenantSetup::class => [
    JobPipeline::make([
        Jobs\CreateDatabase::class,
        Jobs\MigrateDatabase::class,
        Jobs\SeedDatabase::class,
        CreateUser::class, // our job
    ])->send(function (TenantSetup $event) {
        // array elements returned here get passed into job constructors in the pipeline
        return [
            $event->tenant,
            $event->userEmail
        ];
    })->shouldBeQueued(),
],
```

It doesn't matter that the jobs that run before ours don't use given data. We still get it passed through the constructor. (*hey, pretty cool stancl*)

However, be careful when returning anything from the `handle()` method on Jobs. The return value is used as data for jobs running after it.

### Creating a new tenant:

```php
$tenant = Tenant::query()
  ->create([
    // our tenant properties...
  ])
  ->fresh();

// We dispatch our own event manually and pass in our email.
TenantSetup::dispatch($tenant, 'random@fake.com');
```

This should create a new tenant entry and then run the whole pipeline (migrate, seed, etc.) and then create a user entry with the email `random@fake.com`.